# One sql query creating two seperate tables

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Sometimes I like to make an instant copy of a data set outside of the work library, so if development gets messy I always know where my back up copy of a critical data set is located.

Ex - Lets say I have a permanent library already established, named `source`.

I can use a data step in order to create a set (`set_1`) in two different spots.

```
data set_1 source.set_1;
set sashelp.cars;
run;
```

I do understand the below sql (or even a copy procedure for that matter) would be equivalent results to the data step above:

```
proc sql;
create table set_1 as
select distinct *
from sashelp.cars
;
create table source.set_1 as
select *
from set_1
;
quit;
```

I sound lazy here, but I am interested to know if there is a method in `proc sql` in which I can just call two sets to be made off the same query, such as the data step example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.  Stick to using data steps.

Comment: K. Thought I could be lazier.